# trigger updatepanel update using <a href="">

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have created a treeview using the following code in my code-behind.

```
<li><a href=../User/Category.aspx?CategoryID=ff62e353-6eb1-4215-8158-03767d2401de &  isRoot=true>Books</a></li>
```

When user clicks on Books,Category.aspx page opens and all products with this categoryID are loaded in a user control.

I want to trigger update to a updatepanel using this treeview node.Is this possible.

Please suggest some other way to achieve this.

Comment: Take a look at this article [Easily refresh an UpdatePanel, using JavaScript](http://encosia.com/2007/07/13/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/)

Comment: Can't you use a linkbutton here?

Comment: no i can't as there is an activex which renders specific output and input to it in in <ul><li> format only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Script:**

```
function UpdateAndRelocate(updatePanel, url)
{
    __doPostBack(updatePanel, '');
    window.location=url;
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:UpdateAndRelocate('../User/Category.aspx?CategoryID=ff62e353-6eb1-4215-8158-03767d2401deisRoot=true','UpdatePanel1'">Books</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible to do using AJAX as it involves a page switch.I am on a different page and i am navigating to a different page using a href.

Ajax is not for page switching scenerios.